# ghc-mod doesn't see System.Random

Tags: haskell, cabal, ghc-mod

After `cabal install random`, I try `ghc-mod list` but it still doesn't see the package.

```
cabal --version
cabal-install version 1.22.6.0
using version 1.22.4.0 of the Cabal library 

ghc-mod --version
ghc-mod version 5.5.0.0 compiled by GHC 7.10.3
```

I have now also tried adding `random-1.1` to my global stack.yaml (trying to make a simple script here...) and installed via `stack install random` to no avail.

My file seems to run fine with `runhaskell` though.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you type `stack install random`, and then run `stack ghci` or install with stack, the import succeeds

```
> import System.Random  --succeeds
```

If you run ghc outside of stack, it won't necessarily use the same setup.